# AngularJS Server side pagination on mouse scroll

Tags: javascript, angularjs, grails, pagination, infinite-scroll

I am looking for some technique which will get  me  started to do server side pagination on mouse scroll. I have   a large data set which I want to load in chunks and later dynamically load more on mouse scroll but at the server side. I came across [ngInfiniteScroll](http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/index.html#download) but this looks like client side. Is there any method that can help me get started with this ?

Comment: Just implemented that nginfiniteScroll module! As long as your API endpoints accept a `page` type query param, that should work great! I can link my example if you'd like. It's definitely a combination of client/server.

Comment: I would want to modify my API to limit the loading initially and later on mouse scroll load more (because at the moment it is taking lot of time to load everything). Yes I could definitely look at your example

Comment: Well you could limit your result set to a specific count! Here's my example. https://gist.github.com/thoughtpalette/97641665082b7067bad7

Comment: what do you mean by page type query ?

Comment: On scroll the query needs to change so the request grabs the next set of data. So something like `get.("users/?p=1")` then it increments the `p` query when you get to the bottom of the page. `get.("users/?p=2")` Thats how the request gets a new result set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of infinite scroll you could you use following [example](http://jsfiddle.net/vojtiik/n2NHL/) and change the `loadMore()` method so it calls server side just like this.

```
 $scope.loadMore = function () {
        $http.get('/someUrl').
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.items.push(data); 
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
        });
    };
```

Comment: hey I somewhat used the method similar to http://jsfiddle.net/akagr/Eu2FW/4/light/ but everytime the load happends the scroll bar goes back to the top. Is it because may in my loadMore I call a rest service which refreshes the entire section of a page ?

Comment: you shouldn't really refresh all the page. Just get next items via the angularJs $http service (change the "/someurl" to where your data is persisted) and add them to existing array as its in the examples. That should sort you out. The success handler needs bit of work but otherwise its pretty much done.

Answer (score 0):

What ngInfiniteScroll (http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/) does is load you "backend" by calling it each time a user scrolls, therefore what you need to implement is a backend written in your language of your preference that uses JSON (for simplicity sake or xml or whatever that can be parsed) to send data from your "massive dataset" by using some method of ***skip*** and ***steps*** where ***skip*** is the number of elements an index of the database are skipped and ***steps*** are the number of database registers from the the position of the skip index it is going to fetch.

So tell us which database technology are you using in order to implement the skip/steps technique for your infinite scroll.

ie:

MongoDB has Cursor Skip (more on that on the url below)

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/

Comment: using grails with oracle

Comment: You can use this plugin "http://grails.org/plugin/remote-pagination" focusing on "remoteNonStopPageScroll"