# AngularJS Server side pagination on mouse scroll directive event called twice

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to implement server side paging on mouse scroll event to load data when scroll reached to the bottom of the page/div. I did some research and found so many options to do that like ngInfiniteScroll etc.

With this I also found couple of fiddles which were doing the same thing without any third party js dependency as mentioned in the following links-

[AngularJS Server side pagination on mouse scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26384968/angularjs-server-side-pagination-on-mouse-scroll)

http://jsfiddle.net/akagr/Eu2FW/4/light/

http://jsfiddle.net/vojtiik/n2NHL/

I have create also created one POC by referring the last link i.e. http://jsfiddle.net/vojtiik/n2NHL/ and it also works fine in POC.

Following is my code for POC which I have implemented. I have modified it a bit for my convenience but concept is same :

Index.html File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" data-ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/JS/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/JS/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/JS/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/ngInfiniteScroll/ng-infinite-scroll1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/ngInfiniteScroll/ng-infinite-scroll1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/JS/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="app/Controllers/mainCtrl.js"></script>
    <style>
        li {
            height: 120px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
        }

        #fixed {
            height: 400px;
            overflow: auto;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body data-ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <div id="fixed" when-scrolled="loadMore()">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="i in items">{{i.id}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js file :

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.directive('whenScrolled', function () {

    return function (scope, elm, attr) {
        var raw = elm[0];
        var takeRows = scope.takeRows;

        elm.bind('scroll', function () {
            if (raw.scrollTop + raw.offsetHeight >= raw.scrollHeight) {
                // scope.$apply(attr.whenScrolled({ id: takeRows }));
                scope.loadMore(takeRows);
                scope.$apply();
            }
        });
    };
});
```

mainCtrl.js

```
myApp.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.items = [];

    var counter = 0;
    $scope.takeRows = 20;

    $scope.loadMore = function (takeRows) { //Not using takeRows parameter now. Will use it later.

        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.takeRows; i++) {
            $scope.items.push({ id: counter });
            counter += 10;
        }
    };

    $scope.loadMore();
}
]);
```

Now my problem is that I tried the same code in my application and I 
am saw a strange problem. Whenever my scroll reached at the bottom my directive gets triggered correctly. But the if condition satisfied two times and it triggers loadMore() function from directive two times.Condition shown in the following code -

```
elm.bind('scroll', function () {
            if (raw.scrollTop + raw.offsetHeight >= raw.scrollHeight) {
                // scope.$apply(attr.whenScrolled({ id: takeRows }));
                scope.loadMore(takeRows);
                scope.$apply();
            }
        });
```

I tried a lot to find out the cause,but no luck. It may be something that I am doing wrong. Can some one please help me out to solve this problem? 
Any help / Suggestions are appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That means you element has `scroll` event binded twice, You could make sure event has binded once only by `unbind` scroll event before binding it.

**Code**

```
ele.unbind('scroll');
elm.bind('scroll', function() {
    if (raw.scrollTop + raw.offsetHeight >= raw.scrollHeight) {
        // scope.$apply(attr.whenScrolled({ id: takeRows }));
        scope.loadMore(takeRows);
        scope.$apply();
    }
});
```

**Update**

Apart from this code you `scope.loadMore(takeRows)` shouldn't call the service if there is already any service call is in progress, that could be done using promises concept. Programatically implementing this logic would be an good idea.

Comment: Hi pankaj. Thanks for your quick reply. I will try unbinding the scroll event.

Comment: Hi Pankaj. I tried unbinding the scroll event before binding it. But still it fires twice.

Comment: One more thing which I have noticed is that the same code works  fine in Google Chrome and Mozilla. I am facing problem with IE (V 11) only.

Comment: @saajshek it happens everytime or only once a while

Comment: Every time when scroll reached at bottom, it satisfied that if condition twice in directive.

Comment: @could you join this room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75593/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-29714389-angularjs-server-side-pagination-on-m